# iPhone iOS5 How can I present a font type, size, color and alignment widget to the user?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fonts, uitextfield

I have a few UITextFields and I would like the user to be able to change the font's appearance within those fields.

Right now I have a UIToolbar with 5 buttons used for font controls. One for font name, one for size, one for color and one for alignment.

To change font, I display a picker with the fonts family names, letting the user pick default font for that family.

For the font color, I display another toolbar with a font size slider
For font color, I display an open source color picker
For font alignment, I display a button that cycles through the left/center/right alignment.
Finally there's a close button that hides the toolbar.

Currently all of my code is in one controller, but I would like to have it refactored into a separate, reusable class.

Since I'll be rewriting code, **are there any open source font controls like I'm describing above?** Maybe I can just plug in something that's already made into my project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the attributed string example by apple does have a table view-like font controller that includes a preview of what fonts look like. I think extending that controller may be the easiest thing to do:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTextPageViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be very hard at all. Instead of pickers use a scroll view with buttons and labels above them using the font. As for size you could do the same!

This would be easy in Xcode 4, not so sure in 3.X.X

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. I will have to think on it, as I want the user to see a preview of how the font will look in the interface.

Comment: A preview with their text a just a sample of the font?